# Changing a global variable

Tags: javascript, variables

I need your help: I have a variable anima, so when myFunction1() is execulted, it will be set to another value. So when I execute myFunction2(), switch case will work accourding to the value that was set on myFunction1(), and than set anima to another value again.

```
var anima= 1;

function myFunction1(){

switch(anima) {
    case 1:
        alert("initial value");
        break;
    case 2:
        alert(anima);
        break;
    case 3:
        anime4r();
        break;
    case 4:
        anime5r(); 
}
var anima= 2;

}

function myFunction2(){

switch(anima) {
    case 1:
        anime1();
        break;
    case 2:
        alert("it worked");
        break;
    case 3:
        anime4r();
        break;
    case 4:
        anime5r(); 
}
var anima= 1;

}
```

Comment: stop it. global variables are bad.

Comment: Why do keep redefining variables?

Comment: A stupid mistake of mine to keep that " var anima= 2;" in myFunction2()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of the `var` in `var anima= 2;` and `var anima= 1;` (in `function myFunction2()`). You are redefining the variable in a local scope so the change is not to the global variable.